# My female cat hisses and pins down my kitten before licking her and cuddling her?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, communication

I got a kitten a few weeks ago. At first my older female was unhappy with it of course, but no severe fighting, just a hiss or two.

Now she’s recently started to hiss and pin her head down randomly. But yet, she cuddles her and licks her until there’s nothing left to lick.

I am not sure if she likes her or what’s going on. The kitten acts submissively anytime she does that, but she just did it and proceeded to kiss her so? I’m a little confused.

Comment: This sounds like mothering behavior.  Maybe your adult cat is adopting the kitten.

Answer (score 4):

Cats hiss to intimidate another into not attacking, and pinning a cat stops any attack physically plus establishes dominance.

It’s possible your older female is still a bit nervous around the kitten; it’s another predator in “her” territory, after all, plus kittens tend to be rather energetic and “attack” their siblings and mothers as a form of play. So, she is making it clear to the kitten this is grooming time, not playtime. Once the kitten calms down and/or develops a better sense of when she is willing to play, the hissing and pinning will probably stop.